# Basic multiplicity - Getting multiple data

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, People and Colors

People have id, name and colorId (colors they like)
Colors have id and name

People who like 1 color is easy to get data

```
Select People.name as Pname, Colors.name as Cname 
From People, Colors
Where (People.colorId = Colors.id AND People.id = 1)
```

But, how can i do with some people who likes 2 or more colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO **first of all** you need to change your schema to be able to properly store and easily query this kind of data. You need to move your `person <-> color` relation to another (pivot/many-to-many) table.

Proposed schema

```
CREATE TABLE people
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(32));
CREATE TABLE colors
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(32));
CREATE TABLE person_color
    (`person_id` int, `color_id` int);
```

Now you can query your data. To get the colors a person like

```
SELECT p.name p_name, c.name c_name 
  FROM person_color pc JOIN people p
    ON pc.person_id = p.id JOIN colors c
    ON pc.color_id = c.id 
 WHERE p.id = 1
 ORDER BY c.id
```

Sample output:

```
|  P_NAME | C_NAME |
--------------------
| Person1 |  black |
| Person1 |    red |
| Person1 |   blue |
```

or who likes more than one color

```
SELECT p.name p_name, COUNT(*) how_many_colors
  FROM person_color pc JOIN people p
    ON pc.person_id = p.id
 GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Sample output:

```
|  P_NAME | HOW_MANY_COLORS |
-----------------------------
| Person1 |               3 |
```

or get delimited list of colors per person for those who likes more than one color

```
SELECT p.name p_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) colors
  FROM person_color pc JOIN people p
    ON pc.person_id = p.id JOIN colors c
    ON pc.color_id = c.id 
 GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Sample output:

```
|  P_NAME |         COLORS |
----------------------------
| Person1 | black,blue,red |
```

or who likes exactly black and blue and nothing else

```
SELECT p.name p_name
  FROM person_color pc JOIN people p
    ON pc.person_id = p.id JOIN colors c
    ON pc.color_id = c.id 
 WHERE c.name IN('black', 'blue')
 GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = 2
```

Sample output:

```
|  P_NAME |
-----------
| Person1 |
```

etc.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a5815/7)** demo

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
Select People.name as Pname, group_concat(Colors.name) as Cnames
From People join
     Colors
     on People.colorId = Colors.id
group by people.id
having count(*) > 1;
```

However, your original query only gets the colors for the person with `id = 1`.  It has nothing to do with how many colors are produced.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  People.name as Pname, GROUP_CONCAT(Colors.name) as Cname, COUNT(Colors.id) as total_like
From 
  People INNER JOIN Colors ON (People.colorId = Colors.id)
Having 
   total_like > 2
```

P.S. I don't test